# iOS 8 Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to add a keyboard to the UIAlertController.  However, when I click OK to dismiss the UIAlertController, I get this error :**Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 2705787216_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default**.  I am testing this on a real device and can not find any solutions other than to change the hardware options in the simulator.  This has no effect on real device testing.

public class func getReminderView(timeInterval: Int, view: UIView) -> UIAlertController
{

```
var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Reminder",
                                     message: "Set a reminder for the bus.",
                                     preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

refreshAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler()
{ textField -> Void in
    textField.text = "\(timeInterval)"
    textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
}

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default )
{ action in
    let strTime = refreshAlert.textFields![0] as! UITextField
    if(strTime.text != "")
    {
        let time = strTime.text.toInt()!
        if(time < 300)
        {
       //     Alarm.createReminder("Catch the Bus",
       //         timeInterval: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: Double(time * 60)))
        }
        else
        {
      //      Alert.presentErrorSheet("Select a time under 300 minutes",
      //                              view: view.parentViewController!)
        }
    }
    else
    {
    //    Alert.presentErrorSheet("Select a real time!", view: view.parentViewController!)
    }
})

return refreshAlert
```

}